# How to export environment variables from bash to tcsh

Tags: bash, tcsh

I've to run a `.csh` script from a `bash` shell, to accomplish this I'm using `tcsh -c <command>` command but with that I also require environment variables defined in parent `bash` shell. Could someone suggest a way to export environment variables from `bash` to `tcsh`. I would like to have the below structure for my command.

```
$ tcsh -c "env ENV_VAR=${ENV_VAR} /command/to/run <args>"
```

Comment: Environment variables are inherited automatically, you don't need to do anything special. That's the definition of environment variables.

Comment: You don't need to use `tcsh -c` to run a csh script. If the script begins with `#!/usr/bin/tcsh` it will be run with `tcsh`.

Comment: `tcsh -c <command>` executes `<command>` as a tcsh command, but that doesn't affect how the scripts within it are executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the variables to the environment of `tcsh`; the script will inherit them from `tcsh`. (I'm assuming `/command/to/run` is a C-shell script.)

```
$ SOME_VAR="some value" tcsh -c "/command/to/run <args>"
```

Assuming the argument to `-c` isn't some more complicated C-shell expression, you can dispense with the option.

```
$ SOME_VAR="some value" tcsh /command/to/run <args>
```